# how to use a case class object in my class in Scala

Tags: scala

```
package peaceland
class Peacewatcher(idPeaceWatcher: Int, messages: List[Message]) {
 
   case class Message(idPeaceWatcher: Int, location: (Int, Int), surrounding: List[Citizen], words: List[String])
}
```

Each peacewatcher sends a report every minute. One report contains

● peacewatcher id

● peacewatcher current location (latitude, longitude)

● name of surrounding citizen (identify with facial recognition) with their computed «peacescore»

● words heard by the peacewatcher in its surrounding

How to add an abject Message in my class peacewatcher I try to use case class I have an error

Comment: What is `Message`? Where is it defiend?

Comment: Message is a case class

Comment: Where is it defined? Please take the [tour], and read [ask]. Please also provide [mcve].

Comment: I have a class PeaceWatcher I need to use an object Message this is why I use "case class " How to use Message in my class Peacewatcher this is my question

Comment: I'd guess that you defined it in another package, but there are not enough details in your question.

Comment: You should add in the question as well, how are you trying to use the case class and what is the error you are receiving

Comment: If you really have the `case class Message` _inside_ `Peacewatcher` as your code shows, it's quite unusual but you'd refer to it as `Peacewatcher#Message` outside.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with add a message object to a class, that doesn't make much sense. This looks like homework, so I would guess it would be better to ask your professor for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have it defined like this you have to define a `Message` before defining `Peacewatcher`. The code you've pasted won't compile. The most common way of solving this would be to use a companion object with `Message` defined inside. If you come from a Java background it would be an equivalent of a static inner class (you can read more about it [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html)). Here is an example:

```
package peaceland

import peaceland.Peacewatcher.Message

class Peacewatcher(idPeaceWatcher: Int, messages: List[Message]) {
  // Some logic here using constructor arguments
}

object Peacewatcher {
  case class Message(idPeaceWatcher: Int, location: (Int, Int), surrounding: List[Citizen], words: List[String])
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you are a genius